# Using nc to transfer large file

Tags: linux

I have a compressed file size of about 9.5 GB and want to transfer from one server to another server, I tried to use like the below,

server2:

nc -lp 1234 > file.tar.gz

server1:

nc -w 1  1234 < file.tar.gz

its not working.

I tried so many ways.

One machine is CentOS 6.4 and the other one is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you need a hostname in there somewhere?

Comment: is there a reason you can't simply use scp?

Comment: simple scp is breaking after some time, getting broken pipe error... since the file size is 9.5 GB

Comment: @evilotto netcat is a little faster than scp, especially on older machines. If the encryption is not required, netcat is a good solution with less overhead compared scp or rsync over ssh. Over flaky connections I'd use rsync, though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On receiving end:

```
nc -l 1234 > file.tar.gz
```

On sending end:

```
cat file.tar.gz | nc <reciever's ip or hostname> 1234
```

That should work. Depending on the speed, it may take a while but both processes will finish when the transfer is done.

Comment: The transfer is completed but the file size is 0, actually as I told you the file size is 9.6 GB...

Comment: Post the result for your `ls -l` because this worked for me.

Comment: I think now its copying... let me check and will keep posted...

Comment: Can I see the progress of copying.. ?

Comment: You can open another terminal and do something like `watch ls -l file.tar.gz` to track its progress. The size value will update every two seconds.

Comment: yes am able to see the progress... hope there should not be any network disturbance...

Comment: I think `nc` uses TCP instead of something else (UDP) so accurate delivery is prioritized over a timely delivery. Just let it do its thing. ;)

Comment: ok... now suddenly something gone bad and stopped in 1 GB itself, started again...

Comment: I was able to copy a 19 GB hard drive file across servers (/dev/sda1 over to an IMG) so I imagine that, given the internet is uninterupted, this should be easy. Are you doing this inside of your own network or across the internet? How reliable is your connection? In some cases hardware may be easier (removable media, external Hard Drive?)

Comment: Am using across the network, site to site, but we are connected via VPN.

Comment: am using -d in the receiving end, so that nc runs in the background.. lets see this time...

Comment: I didnt get through... suspect problem in network...

Comment: The more points the data has to go through, the increased likely hood that the transfer will fail. If you're not limited to one shell at a time, don't put it in the background just in case. See if `nohup` will help if a VPN failure is the case.

Answer (score 4):

From the [`nc(1)` man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=nc):

> **`-l`**      Used to specify that nc should listen for an incoming connection rather than initiate
>                a connection to a remote host.  It is an error to use this option in conjunction with
>                the -p, -s, or -z options.

So your use of `-p` is wrong.

Use on server2:

```
nc -l 1234 > file.tar.gz
```

And on server1:

```
nc server2 1234 < file.tar.gz
```

Comment: The transfer is completed but the file size is 0, actually as I told you the file size is 9.6 GB...

Answer (score 1):

from the sender

```
nc -v -w 30 1337 - l < filename
```

where "-v" from verbose, "-w 30" for a wait before and after 30 sec for the connection, "1337" port number, "-l" tell nc that this is a sender

from the receiver
`nc -v -w 2 ip_add_of_sender 1337 > filename`